# Amazon EMR while Submitting Job for Apache-Flink getting error with Hadoop recoverable

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, hadoop2

```
Added Depedency Pom Details :

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-filesystem_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-s3-fs-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-shaded-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.529</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-connectors</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Recoverable writers on Hadoop
>   are only supported for HDFS and for Hadoop version 2.7 or newer   at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopRecoverableWriter.(HadoopRecoverableWriter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.createRecoverableWriter(HadoopFileSystem.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.createRecoverableWriter(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.(Buckets.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink$RowFormatBuilder.createBuckets(StreamingFileSink.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.initializeState(StreamingFileSink.java:327)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:738)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:289)
>     at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flink uses something called a [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to load components needed to [interface with pluggable File Systems](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/#adding-a-new-pluggable-file-system-implementation). If you care to see where Flink does this in code, head over to `org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem`. Take note of the `initialize` function, which makes use of the `RAW_FACTORIES` variable. `RAW_FACTORIES` is created by the function `loadFileSystems`, which you can see makes use of Java's `ServiceLoader`.

The file system components need to be setup prior to your application starting on Flink. This implies that your Flink application does not need to bundle these components, they should be provided for your application.

EMR does not provide the S3 file system components that Flink needs to use S3 as a streaming file sink out of the box. This exception is being thrown not because the version isn't high enough, but because Flink loaded the HadoopFileSystem in the absence of a FileSystem that matched the `s3` scheme ([see code here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.8.1/flink-filesystems/flink-hadoop-fs/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/fs/hdfs/HadoopRecoverableWriter.java#L56)).

You can see if your file systems are loading by enabling DEBUG logging level for my Flink application which EMR lets you do in configurations:

```
{
    "Classification": "flink-log4j",
    "Properties": {
      "log4j.rootLogger": "DEBUG,file"
    }
  },{
    "Classification": "flink-log4j-yarn-session",
    "Properties": {
      "log4j.rootLogger": "DEBUG,stdout"
    }
  }
```

The relevant logs are available in the YARN Resource Manager, looking at the logs for an individual node. Searching for the string `"Added file system"` should help you locate all successfully loaded file systems.

Also handy in this investigation was to SSH to the master node and use the [flink-scala REPL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/scala_shell.html), where I could see what FileSystem Flink decided to load given a file URI.

The solution is to drop the JAR for the S3 file system implementation into `/usr/lib/flink/lib/` prior to starting your Flink application. This can be done with a bootstrap action that grabs the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` or `flink-s3-fs-presto` (depending on which implementation you are using). My bootstrap action script looks something like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/flink/lib
cd /usr/lib/flink/lib

sudo curl -O https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/flink/flink-s3-fs-hadoop/1.8.1/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.8.1.jar
```

Comment: I struggled a lot around flink-s3-fs-hadoop and flink-s3-fs-presto in EMR. It's not easy to get the thing right as the bootstrap actions in EMR are triggered before any frameworks gets installed... Directly fetching the right jars from repos during bootstrap is definitely the way to go.

Comment: EMR already provides the libs, you just need to make a copy: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/` then
`sudo cp /usr/lib/flink/opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.11.2.jar /usr/lib/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/`

Comment: If I have a running cluster and running Flink application, how can I restart the application for the new jar to be picked up?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Flink's `StreamingFileSink` with exactly once guarantees, you need to use Hadoop >= `2.7`. Versions below `2.7` are not supported. Hence, please make sure that you are running an up to date Hadoop version on EMR.

Comment: Current version i am using is 2.8.5 . Below dependency i am using

Comment: Do you use a Flink version which is bundled with Hadoop? Could you share the complete classpath with me? You'll find it as one of the first lot statements in the jobmanager.log.

Comment: I don't see them. You could also update your question to include it.

Comment: I posted the dependency lib on question answered section.

Comment: added pom details on question also.

Comment: I still need the classpath which you find logged as one of the first statements in your logs. It should look like: `2019-04-02 15:15:07,501 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Classpath: :/Users/till/work/flink/workspace/flink/flink-dist/target/flink-1.9-SNAPSHOT-bin/flink-1.9-SNAPSHOT/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.9-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/till/work/flink/workspace/flink/flink-dist/target/flink-1.9-SNAPSHOT-bin/flink-1.9-SNAPSHOT/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191495/discussion-between-sudhanshu-lenka-and-till-rohrmann).

Comment: send you details in chat , pls check

Answer (score 0):

In addition of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309829/4282745

I suggest to not enable the presto `s3` plugins during the bootstrap action script as Flink is not installed yet, but rather to add an EMR step before Flink is launched.

For example, the below script runs as an EMR step ensures that the version of the plugins provided by the EMR is indeed used:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/flink/plugins/s3-fs-presto
sudo cp /usr/lib/flink/opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-* /usr/lib/flink/plugins/s3-fs-presto/
```

As per EMR 6.14.0, `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` is available by default here: `/usr/lib/flink/plugins/s3`